# spyder 3.7 not responding once a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, text-editor

In one of my pc, I have spyder 3.78 installed from Anaconda. it is not responding once a while, so I have to wait for 10-20 seconds in order for me to be able to edit the file. It happens quite often. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: check the memory usage and are you using kite?

Comment: I hate Spyder, it's unbearable slow sometimes, but you can try this, ```spyder --reset``` from a terminal. REMEMBER, that you will have to change the interface settings all over again.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Our editor has several performance issues. Most of them will be fixed in our 4.2.0 version, to be released this weekend. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. That is awesome!!!! Thanks for developing a fantastic product for us!!!